# Auto completar DBLookupComboBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho um DBLookupComboBox2 com as seguintes informações:

```
42-batata
45-cebola
78-caneca
49-faca
79-livro
```

Se for digitado o número é feito a busca, mas com letras não funciona. Por exemplo eu quero digitar "bata" e já vir selecionado o registro "42-batata".

No evento KeyPress estou consultando por like o que for digitado no DBLookupComoBox. 
Minha dúvida é a seguinte existe a possibilidade de aparecer dentro do componente o que eu for digitando, do jeito que eu estou fazendo até agora se eu digitar "ba" não aparece visualmente dentro do componente.

Comment: Testei aqui, e realmente não faz, teria que fazer um `hack`, para manipular os dados, o complicado é atribuir um novo valor para o comboBox, não tem atributo pronto para isso. Já considerou tropar para um `TDBComboBox` ?

Answer (score 1):

O acho que o objeto dblookup não realizará o comportamento que tu deseja.

Mas segundo o primeiro paradigma do programador que diz o seguinte:
"Código bom é aquele que funciona"

Para resolver este problema poderá fazer o SQL da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT concat(cast(id as char(5)),'-' , nome ) as ID_NOME, tabela.*  FROM TABELA
```

Faça as ligações necessárias no dblookup para o novo campo ID_NOME e você conseguira ter a funcionalidade desejada.